# Error exporting release too iOS arm-apple-darwin9-as.exe not found

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, flash-builder

I have an application that I build in Flash Builder 4.6. The application is running fine on my Android device.
I'm now trying to export a release build to the apple iPhone. The first time I tried, I got an error that I haven't installed the apple SDK.  I download the ADOBE AIR SDK 3.1.0.4880 and copied the three folders over to my C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0\lib\aot
Now when I try, I get the error that the GPL component arm-apple-darwin9-as.exe is missing. When I look in the folder I see a file called arm-apple-darwin9-as but not an executable (exe).
I looked in all folders of the dowloaded SDK and I don't see any executable.

Kim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying another download on my Mac, i got the right files when the Mac unpacked the SDK, I transfred them to my windows computer and I was able to create a iOS app.